# What is meant by\$ I_{peak} \$current in CMOS inverter?

Tags: power, mosfet, inverter, cmos, vlsi

This is a snap from Chapter number 5 CMOS inverter, [Digital integrated circuit by Jan M Rabaey](https://booksonweb.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/digital-integrated-circuits-a-design-perspective-by-jan-m-rabaey.pdf) .
I just wanted to know from where this \$I_{peak}\$  is measured. The direct path current exist till the output goes from \$V_{tn}\$ to \$V_{DD}-V_{tp}\$. But this current is peak value of which current? Current through the PMOS drain /source or the NMOS drain/source? While simulating which of the four currents should I take?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The current author talks about is the short-circuit current \$I_{sc}\$ relevant to transient power dissipation in a CMOS inverter.

\$I_{sc}\$ flows from \$V_{DD}\$ to \$V_{SS}\$ when both PMOS and NMOS are conducting for a brief period of time while switching is happening at the input of the inverter. It is modelled/approximated as a spike within this time interval.

From the same [book](https://booksonweb.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/digital-integrated-circuits-a-design-perspective-by-jan-m-rabaey.pdf):

[image]

You can measure this current as the drain-source current through either PMOS or NMOS within the time interval where 'shorting' is happening. \$I_{peak}\$ is the peak value of \$I_{sc}\$.

A [crude circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEDoE4DMAWATKhl0A2AdnVW0gA5lJkRN1kBTAWjDACgAzEbTWvrXSRMvfiHTZw0JDEjZuY2qkISRIFRMZgZUWAoDua0dgSrhJytUgcjFkJSHrComwHNjvK58m0-HACVPFwkEKRC-elpZKD0EDgBjeklwYlUGKVNVP1h4SFQCwqLi1Ho0IsISeRFCSlV4jwzeYikm31ibIyas5MyWqFstVTA0zxHswft2KSnRzrHR%202w%20Aa6UsGxqJvHViVrwTb3qHfmiY8WiVImkjePyA%20pN6z08iBgRvmJIYmIEMLJKGB9nJIJwjLcvNQlt4bAAnB7gQi0RyIyJgeCDCE7LH3eYooHI2jTAZBYmYY5I%20jPWjiGI5eJGFEhfEbXZYylYuaYw47QRXXZ8zR8k6DYWjPl8077CHbQ42AAevDAFMY2HWlXo4FoADUAJYAOw4ioYpXYpUwCFNy016JA2oA9gBXAAugQctBCxM9vC1vF02F09I49t9EWSCEYILgaVwZAt6A2sn0MSktsYAEkAM4JAA6mYAFAAHAC29szAEpg%20AIGGGBGXvAYxhUPHEy82xBUxAM9m8-n9aWK1XWbX0AhRLao-k0mZTD6JzNeFIBIu9fq%20wFywAaPMOl19gDilZD2FUo-rU6bcYjbbkc9VvHMIHTAGE%20wATXXZgAWAENYW4TDHrwpS1vk1i5NGhCxi2N5ziC0FICYIESHaBp9i%20AAyADSlZAA) to simulate the behavior of this current.

Comment: the current through PMOS and NMOS are different. So which one should I take?

Comment: @HariKrishna If the output is switching 1→0 you can measure it at the PMOS side, otherwise NMOS side.

Comment: this is what I thought. But my actual issue just starts from this idea. So theoretically this will be from V<sub>tn</sub> to V<sub>dd</sub> - V<sub>tp</sub>. But then when input varies , it will take some time to reflect at the gate? Then the short circuit current duration will be different? Also my inverter is not going directly to gnd or vdd. It's having some increase then decrease, at that case from where should I measure ? @mitu

Comment: Okay delay can be neglected ? What about the increasing and decreasing ? To be precise , I used a back to back inverter. So in that input is varying from 1.8v to roughly 0.9V and later it goes back to 1.8v. So it's like vdd to 1/2Vdd and then back to Vdd. In that case what's the short circuit current l?

Comment: The back to back inverter was used in a Strong ARM latch

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/yjo43v92 --- I have attached a 'crude' circuit to simulate the behavior. You can see how Isc(pmos) and Isc(nmos) varies during switching. You can vary R/C at load/input to control rise time and load capacitances and see how it affects the short circuit currents. One of them contributes to short-circuit power dissipation, either current thru pmos/nmos.

Comment: For eg., if the output is switching from 0 to 1, the current through nmos is the one contributing to short-circuit power dissipation. You can suppress this 'undesirable' current to almost zero by increasing load capacitance or decreasing rise time at input in the simulation. In this way short-circuit dissipation approx goes 0.

Comment: I have done that simulation. The thing is capacitance and all such parameters are fixed for my circuit , I  cant vary them for the question. All I want is to accurately measure it rather than try to reduce. This is because other power consumptions(static , charging cap etc and delay etc) need to be kept minimal and resistor /capacitances can not be varied. @mitu

Comment: You can measure it in either pmos or nmos then. Depending on the switching. The other side current is relevant only for capacitive-load power dissipation. It has nothing to do short-circuit power.

Comment: Can you please look at the image I added. So in that please look inside red box, thats when the inverters are ON. Look. In that one is decreasing , so I can take it through PMOS. but the other one is decreasing and then increasing    @mitu

Comment: You are simulating voltage on it (which voltages,?), not current.

Comment: Yes I am simulating voltage , it's back to back inverter. So input for y pair is output of x pair and vice versa

Comment: I am not sure which voltages you speak about and hence how's it's relevant to short circuit current.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127299/discussion-between-hari-krishna-and-mitu-raj).

Answer (score 0):

The peak current is the current need to charge (discharge) the gate of the MOSFET and it's mostly limited by the gate resistance and other parasitics (wiring inductance and various capacitances). In fact the gate current will also charge the parasitic gate-drain and gate-source capacitance (very important fact for power work, but it seems your book is about logic).

The basic idea about CMOS is that *at rest* nothing flows and bias current is almost null but during switch the gates need to be charged/discharged and that creates the dynamic dissipation which is the bulk of heat generation in CMOS logic (there's a little bit of cross conduction during switch, too).

The current spikes are not actually triangles but exponentials IIRC (the gates are more or less capacitors).

EDIT OOPS I read the question bad. Your peak current is *actually* the cross conduction between the CMOS pair. While one FET opens the other one is still closing so there is some VDD-VSS shoot through. It depends on the overlap of the switching curves of the P- and the N- channels

Comment: How do I find that current using simulation? I have been thinking about it for like 2 days. Still I am not sure which current is the short circuit/shoot throo/direct path current for which the peak is taken. Is it current through PMOS or NMOS? Some current through Mosfet is used to charge the capacitor.

Comment: just measure the drain current in one of the MOSFETs… during cross conduction it is substantially the same